# How can I shut down xserver without root access

Tags: linux

Is there any way to shut down the xserver on linux without root access? I tried ctrl-alt-f1. It seems there is still xserver running. Thank you.

Comment: Try Ctrl+Alt+Backspace.

Comment: .. and hope that it doesn't restart :)

Answer (score 3):

Ctrl-Alt-Backspace

will usually kill the X-server.

Be aware that many linux distributions will automatically relaunch X.

Answer (score 1):

The X server will still run when you switch virtual consoles. You can even run multiple X servers, each on a different virtual console.

If you want it *gone*, you have two options:

- kill the *magic xinit process*
- kill the X server

If you kill the last process started out of `~/.xinitrc` or the last process started via the display manager (`xdm`, `gdm`, `kdm`, `lxdm`, etc.), this will typically also ask the other processes to close, semi-gracefully, and might save some additional state.

If you kill the X server directly, all those clients will drastically lose their connection to the X server, and might not handle it well. But it can be an excellent tool to recover a broken or wedged X, and it is sure easier to type `killall X` rather than trying to figure out which process is the *magic xinit process*.

You can kill the X server from another virtual console or from `ssh` or `telnet`, or any other mechanism that will let you run a command `killall X` or send the X server process a signal.

Comment: Of course, that requires superuser privileges, so your answer to the question asked has to be "No.".  (-:

Comment: @JdeBP, for the last two paragraphs, yes; but killing the magic xinit/display manager process will also kill the running X. Whether or not it _restarts_ X is a site configuration question. :)

Comment: It's also part of what an answer must address.  Notice that the questioner didn't ask how to kill X, but how to _shut down_ X.